# Access Control Service 2.0 available for Windows Server?

Tags: acs

I want to rely on Windows Identity foundation for my web site and web services authentication. Is ACS available for Windows Server? Do I have to rely on Azure or can I run it at my hosting environment?

Comment: figured it out. It is not available

Answer (score 0):

The functional equivalent of ACS on-premises is ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services). Look at V2. It is a component of the OS.

I say "equivalent" because it is an STS, but there's no parity between ACS and ADFS. Some things are the same, but not everything.